# read.table ignoring white spaces and converting to character

Tags: r, csv

I am reading a csv-file into R using `read.table`.
When I open the file in a text editor, it looks like this :

```
variable 1;variable 2;variable 3; ...
name1;0,00;1,00;0,00;...
name2;1,00;2,00;0,00;...
...
```

As you can see, the first variable consist of characters, while all of the other ones are numeric **but with comma seperated decimals**.

Note: Unfortunately, there are also some that are encoded as `--` instead of `0,00`

Now when I use `read.table` I specify

```
dec=","
sep=";"
header=TRUE
stringsAsFactors=FALSE
```

but this does not work. There are two issues:

- The headers now look like this: `variable.1` `variable.2` ...
- The columns are all characters such as `"0,00"`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read.csv2` which has `sep = ';'` and `dec = ','` as default value. To keep the spaces in column names include `check.names = FALSE`.

```
data <- read.csv2('filename.csv', check.names = FALSE)
```

---

For example if we copy the text from OP as text.

```
text = 'variable 1;variable 2;variable 3
name1;0,00;1,00;0,00
name2;1,00;2,00;0,00'

data <- read.csv2(text = text, check.names = FALSE)
data

#      variable 1 variable 2 variable 3
#name1          0          1          0
#name2          1          2          0

str(data)

#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ variable 1: num  0 1
# $ variable 2: num  1 2
# $ variable 3: num  0 0
```

Comment: Thanks, "check.names" helps. But do you know why the columns are read in as e.g. "0,00" instead of true numerics?

Comment: Not sure, if I copy the data from your post as text, I can read the data as numeric. I have updated the post to show that. Do you have different data then what you have shown?

Comment: Yes, mine is way larger. I suppose I have some inconsistencies in my formats. For example, there is a -- where there should be a 0,00 in the csv-file. Is there any where to force R to convert to numeric If possible? So that 0,00 becomes numeric 0 and -- just stays a character?

Comment: You should have included this information in your original post. We cannot have a column with mixed datatypes. A column can either be numeric or character. You can exclude them with `na.strings` like `read.csv2('filename.csv', check.names = FALSE, na.strings = '--')` so `--` is read as `NA` and `0,00` would be read as number 0.

Comment: Awesome! I only just realized this, I will add it to my post @Ronak Shah